# null or not an object

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have a JSP page which has TD as follows:

```
<td align="right" id="DDD" style="display:none;">
    <label for="DDD" accesskey="A">DDD:&nbsp; </label>
</td>
<td id="DDD1" style="display:none;">
    <html:text property="DDD" styleId="DDD" readonly="true" styleClass="text" style="width: 8em; border: 0px solid buttonFace; background-color: transparent;" />
</td>
```

and the TD display is none/block based on Javascript. This is the javascript:

```
if (caseInfo[4] == "2")
{
    document.getElementById('DDD').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('DDD').disabled = false; 
    document.getElementById('DDD1').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('DDD1').disabled = false; 
    if (caseInfo[2].length >0 && caseInfo[2] != "NULL")
    {
        alert(caseInfo[2]);
        document.forms[0].DDD.value = caseInfo[2];
    }
    else
    {
        document.forms[0].DDD.value = "";
    }
    alert("DDD1"+document.forms[0].DDD1.value);
}
```

When I run the application, in UI I see the lable but not the input fields and I see `document.forms.0.DDD1` is null or not an object in the line `document.getElementById('DDD1').style.display = 'block';`. This property is already set in form.

Any idea why it does not get displayed?

Comment: Your HTML code does not include a `form` tag. Do you have one?

Comment: Yes it does, and the other td's do work.

Comment: Can you select the other `td` tags using `document.forms[0].DDD`? `document.getElementById('DDD1')` seems like a better option if you want to select the `td`.

Comment: yes the lable for DDD works though.

Comment: Can you please show the working code? `document.forms[0].DDD` should not work as far as I know.

Comment: document.getElementById('DDD').style.display = 'block'; 
    document.getElementById('DDD').disabled = false;

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? It looks broken.

Comment: Im trying to display/block a label and its input field based on a condiotn from javascript. what is broken here?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code. But the alert is broken. `document.forms[0].DDD1` does not exist.

Comment: I recommend you to use jQuery to select the elements instead of your mix of getElementById() and document.forms[0].